# remote debugging in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, remote-debugging

I want to access DB in my colleague system SQL Server 2014.
I connect to his system in my SQL Server management Studio and access it.

But the issue is when I try to debug any Stored Procedures in my colleague's DB, it shows the following error

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   (mscorlib)
>
> Unable to access the SQL Server debugging interface. Access is denied.
>   Can not connect to Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on
>   the remote computer.

could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

`SQLCMD -S .\MYSQLSERVER2008 -U YourUsername -P Password -i C:\Database\script.sql`

For more Details :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. but could you please explain what to store in script.sql file. I stored as "exec SPBULKIMPORTSHIPMENTDETAILS 10446,1" in script.sql file, when I run this command through command prompt, it shows error message as could not find Stored procedure