# How is remote debugging allowed on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, vpn

How is remote debugging allowed on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

This stackoverflow post
[remote debugging in sql server management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152172/remote-debugging-in-sql-server-management-studio)
seems to mention the problem someone has faced by, using SQL Server Management Studio, they had difficulties using a remote database.
That is not the issue I am having.

I am already remoting into a server and using the SQL Server Management Studio there and I get this error:

[image]

I want to be able to instruct the IT department there on what they should do to fix this issue.

Comment: If you are remoted into the server, no firewall settings need to be changed.  Also this is a development server, right?  You should never use TSQL debugging on a production server.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Are you certain that no firewall settings are required? This link is of interest:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f57e3d70-9084-43de-9847-d69a3aa80ed9/enable-remote-debug-tsql-in-sqlserver?forum=sqlgetstarted


[QUOTE]
only members of the sysadmin fixed server role are allowed to debug in SQL Server

Firewall port 135 should be open on both machines

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s0fk6z6e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024.aspx
[/QUOTE]